# MVC Spring Implementation - error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a MVC Spring controller, in the Imp file, I have:

```
import com.ish.system.dao.UserDAO;

public class CustomImpl implements CustomService {

UserDAO   userDAO = null;

public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
  return userDAO;
}

public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
  this.userDAO = userDAO;
}

public String ServiceType(userId) {

User user = userDAO.findById(userId);

...
```

Here is the error in the console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ish.smdb.service.impl.CustomImpl.ServiceType(CustomImpl.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ServiceType", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String ServiceType(

            Locale locale,
            Model model) {
        String result = custom.ServiceType();

    return result;
}
```

Here is the bean:

```
<bean id="Custom" parent="baseTransactionProxy"> 
  <property name="target"> 
    <bean id="CustomImpl" class="com.is.sm.service.impl.CustomImpl"> 
      <property name="userDAO" ref="UserDAO" /> 
    </bean> 
  </property> 
</bean>
```

For sure userDAO is null. But I didn't find the reson. What am I wrong?

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace?

Comment: Can you tell me what is that? I just trace the code by out put print.

Comment: Can you post your controller code how you are calling ServiceType and how you are initializing userDAO?

Comment: What above says, you say for sure userDAO is null, that's your error. it's null.. how is your class being initialized? surely userDAO has to be set somewhere or injected.

Comment: I just posted my controller. Can you tell me how can I initialized that?

Comment: Before this `custom.ServiceType();` You should have set userDAO object like: `UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();custom.setUserDAO(userDAO);`.

Comment: I have to mention that the controller is inside the class:@RequestMapping("/customprop")
public class CustomPropertyController {....}

Comment: I am going to put that there...

Comment: It doesn't accept the UserDao. It says: Cannot instantiate the type UserDAO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomImpl bean has dependency to UserDAO, So UserDAO bean must be injected to CustomImpl bean,
please post your xml config file, where you have defined your beans .

update:

here is a solution, you can use spring annotation for injection:

in your UserDAOImpl calss(UserDAO interface implementatoin) use:

```
@Repository(value = "userDAO")
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {....}
```

then in your CustomImpl  class:

```
@Autowired
UserDAO userDAO ;
```

Comment: Here is the bean that I defined: <bean id="Custom" parent="baseTransactionProxy"> <property name="target"> <bean id="CustomImpl" class="com.is.sm.service.impl.CustomImpl"> <property name="userDAO" ref="UserDAO" /> </bean> </property> </bean>